# merging two small pieces of jquery codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following are two pieces of jquery code. First one prints a text message when clicked on a link, and the second slides down a div when click on a link. I want to merge second code into first one, so that when I click the link, it displays the message (as the first code does), and also slides down the #votebox (as done in second code, and show content in that.
I will be very thankful for any help.

```
$("a.vote_up").click(function(){

the_id = $(this).attr('id');
$("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut("fast");
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "action=vote_up&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
        url: "votes.php",
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("span#votes_up"+the_id).fadeOut();
            $("span#votes_up"+the_id).html(msg);
            $("span#votes_up"+the_id).fadeIn();

            //Here, I want to slide down the votebox and content div (from code below).

        }
    });
});
```

The following code slides down votebox div and displays content in it, I want to include that in the above code.

```
$("a.vote_up").click(function(){
var id=$(this).attr("id");
var name=$(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&name='+ name;
//I want to include this votebox in above code.
$("#votebox").slideDown("slow");
$("#flash").fadeIn("slow");

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "rating.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#flash").fadeOut("slow");
//and want to use this div as well.
$("#content").html(html);
} 
});
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post the markup so that we have some context for what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is to define a seperate function for voteDown and call it from the success function:
e.g

```
$("a.vote_up").click(function(){

the_id = $(this).attr('id');
$("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut("fast");
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "action=vote_up&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
        url: "votes.php",
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("span#votes_up"+the_id).fadeOut();
            $("span#votes_up"+the_id).html(msg);
            $("span#votes_up"+the_id).fadeIn();
                        var that = this;
            voteDown.call(that);

        }
    });
});




function voteDown() 
{
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    var name=$(this).attr("name");
    var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&name='+ name;
    $("#votebox").slideDown("slow");
    $("#flash").fadeIn("slow");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rating.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#flash").fadeOut("slow");
            //and want to use this div as well.
            $("#content").html(html);
        } 
    });
}
```

**Edit**: Corrected the JS for Votedown function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesnt work. Both codes work perfectly separately, however by combining it does not work (neither it prints nor slides).

Comment: Oops.. There was an error in the voteDown function definition. Corrected it. Try now..